# Angular service worker with webpack (without CLI)

Tags: angular, webpack

I've a pretty large angular project that is built using webpack (I'm working with Microsoft's template of ASP.NET core). Is there any way I can use @angular/service-worker?

I've already tried adding the package and importing it, but the service worker never gets built. There's no error, but I get nothing. A new CLI project built with the flag works as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was struggling with this as well since i'm not using the CLI. I managed to get it working by including these scripts in npm scripts.

```
    "ngsw-config": "node_modules/.bin/ngsw-config dist src/ngsw-config.json",
    "ngsw-copy": "cp node_modules/@angular/service-worker/ngsw-worker.js dist/",
    "build-ngsw": "npm run ngsw-config && npm run ngsw-copy"
```

Include "build-ngsw" in your production build script.

The first script creates the ngsw.json file in your dist folder by reading the ngsw-config.json (which you'll have to create). The second script copies the actual angular service worker from @angular/service-worker to the dist folder.

Import and register the service worker. See step 3 in this tutorial [Angular Service Worker Getting Started](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started).

Answer (score 6):

For non-cli projects built with webpack, you might not need using Angular Service Worker at all. [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) is nice library for generating service workers which has a decent webpack plugin.

```
npm install --save-dev workbox-webpack-plugin
```

webpack.config:

```
import { GenerateSW } from 'workbox-webpack-plugin'
// const {GenerateSW} = require('workbox-webpack-plugin')
```

where at default it will generate service worker that precaches your webpack output with

```
plugins: [
    // other webpack plugins
    new GenerateSW()
]
```

You can then install this generated service worker after you are bootstrapping your angular application like:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {

    if( !('serviceWorker' in navigator) ){
        console.warn('Too bad, Service worker is not supported in current browser')
        return
    }

    window.navigator.serviceWorker
        .register(`/service-worker.js`, { scope: '/' })
        .then(registration => console.log(`Service worker registration succeeded`))
        .catch(error => console.log(`Service worker registration failed`))  
})
```

provided that your server is serving from webpack's `publicPath`. For more complex scenarios please refer to its docs: [workbox-webpack-plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin), however, let me highlight few common scenarios here:

**I. Precaching non-webpack assets**

If you want to precache assets that are not managed by webpack, use `globDirectory` and `globPatterns` options to find them like:

```
new GenerateSW({
     globDirectory: '.',
     globPatterns: ['assets/**/*.{svg, png}']
})
```

Resulting glob asset url (which you can find in `service-worker.js` **self.__precacheManifest**) will be resolved against glob directory, meaning your server should serve `/assets/`.

**II. Precaching server-generated assets**

It's might be common that your index.html is server-generated, in which case you might want to use `templatedUrl` to specify which routes to precache and how to revision retrieved assets. This is handy to use together with `navigateFallback` to make sure we gracefully fallback to our index.html when accessing non-precached route.

```
new GenerateSW({
    globDirectory: '.',
    globPatterns: [],
    templatedUrls: {
        '/': ['templates/Index.html']
    }
    navigateFallback: '/'
})
```

**templateUrl** specify the route you want to precache and a glob-pattern to find a resource that will be used to revision the retrieved response from this URL. Make sure you have `globDirectory` specified, otherwise plugin will fail with confusing error. As mentioned in [workbox/issues/763](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/763#issuecomment-327254503), md5 hashes of files specified will be used to revision retrieved asset, which will be valid as long as `/templates/Index.html` is not changing. Normally, if you use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to inject your bundle **(with hash)** into `Index.html` template, `service-worker.js` precache manifest revision will change as desired.

**III. Cache API Responses on runtime**

You might often want to also cache some API response and lets say user profile icons that appear in your site's dynamic content. In such we can use network-first strategy for our API to always fetch from the network if available and cache-first strategy for profile icons with something like:

```
new GenerateSW({
    runtimeCaching: [{
        urlPattern: /^http[s]*:\/{2}[\w.:-]+\/api\//,
        handler: 'networkFirst'
    }, {
        urlPattern: /^http[s]*:\/{2}[\w.:-]+\/profile_icons\//,
        handler: 'cacheFirst'
    }]
})
```